# Remove listener for a Backbone event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am wondering how would I remove a listener to `Backbone.history.on()`? `.off()` did not work for me.

```
Backbone.history.on('all', function() {
  doStuff();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`off` works as it should be, and here's a `Router` which proves it:

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'off': 'offAll',
        '*actions': 'index',

    },

    initialize: function(opt) {

        Backbone.history.on('all', this.all);
    },

    index: function() {
        console.log('route');

    },

    offAll: function() {
        console.log('offAll');

        // remove only this one listener
        Backbone.history.off('all', this.all);
    },

    all: function(){
        console.log('all test');
    }

});
```

Navigating to anything other than `#/off` will display :

```
route
all test
```

Then, navigating to `#/off` will display:

```
offAll
```

Then, `all test` never shows up.

## Backbone's event [`.off`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off) function

> ```
> // Removes just the `onChange` callback.
> object.off("change", onChange);
>
> // Removes all "change" callbacks.
> object.off("change");
>
> // Removes the `onChange` callback for all events.
> object.off(null, onChange);
>
> // Removes all callbacks for `context` for all events.
> object.off(null, null, context);
>
> // Removes all callbacks on `object`.
> object.off();
> ```

Comment: How can I ensure that I only remove that one anonymous function?

Comment: @Jon I edited my answer to include the desired behavior.